# I have extra script appears in browser that dose not appear in the source code

Tags: javascript, php, html, iis

When I load My website from Oman there is extra script being loaded that does not exist in my source code. This script dose not appear when I load from any other country. This script makes my website take more time to timeout using chrome, while it is loaded successfully from edge.

I am hosting my website on IIS, it is a php, html and js website only.
I using IIS10, PHP5 and MySQL 5.7

I am hosting my website in Oman, and this IP is owned by one of the ISP in Oman

Here is the script which appears exactly before the end of the body tag

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' id ='1qa2ws' charset='utf-8' src='http://212.72.31.34:8080/www/default/base.js'{$MarketingParam$}></script></body>
```

1- Is that really injected script? 
2- If I can not remove it, How to block it from being called?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an ISP injecting the script. You can stop it by moving your website from insecure HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: My website have problem with the HTTPS, is there any other way to block this ip form IIS ?
by the way, is it legal ?

I had implemented HTTPS 6 months ago, while it was implemented all of the sudden all IIS requests goes in long loop without timeout or error logs, is that also related? for example my ISP is not getting any access so it freezes the requests somehow

Answer (score -1):

I found one small solution,

you can either delete the  tag where ISP is looking for it to inject.
as they mentioned in other questions, browsers are closing the tags by itself.

or adding the following script instead of the tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append("</bo"+"dy>");
    });
</script>
```

adding the scripts worked for me.